# What is the best way to represent intraday time HH:MM:SS in c++11

Tags: c++, date, c++11, time, c++-chrono

C++11 [chrono](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) provides concepts: [clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialClock), [time_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point), [duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) and in [Howard Hinnant's date.h library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) there are additional functions to manipulate dates and time [with motivating examples/reciepes](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes). However I have trouble to express general time-points such as ten o'clock. 
Should general intraday time point be expressed

- with duration: today + duration
- creating custom clock choosing epoch of any given day ie: today
- ????

what is the best way in c++11 to get good representation of a general intraday time in the format of HH:MM:SS?

```
seq = [2018-01-01 09:29:00UTC, 2018-01-01 09:29:58UTC,..., 2018-01-01 09:35:00UTC, ..., 2018-01-01 16:29:00UTC, 2018-01-01 16:30:00UTC]
for time in seq
    time > "09:30:00" and time < "16:00:00" do some work;
```

Comment: Maybe the number of seconds elapsed since midnight? The best way in terms of what? The question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: What time zone?  UTC?  The computer's current local time zone?  Some other specific time zone?

Comment: You're voting for 'duration'. The question is unclear because I am not able to conceptualise it. You see I could make a custom clock with epoch midnight of a given day, so now 10o'clock is indeed a time point or you can count from midnight then you have 'duration'. Of course there is the alternative to take each general time point with unix epoch and when comparing it to specific time points downcast the latter. Did this make more sense? or not at all?

Comment: @HowardHinnant  yes, exactly! Local time zone is preferable. Would you prefer it to be expressed custom_clock  | duration | ??? . The goal is to able to do comparison between other time_points with system_clock | utc clock | local clock | ...  so a data stream with time field can be partitioned with set inclusion/exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Howard Hinnant's date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date), 10am local today is:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto zt = make_zoned(current_zone(), local_days{2018_y/jan/15} + 10h);
    std::cout << zt << '\n';
}
```

which just output for me:

```
2018-01-15 10:00:00 EST
```

`local_days` is used to convert a year/month/day into a `local_time` with a precision of `days`.  You can add any `chrono::duration` to that, using any units you want.  Then you can pair that `local_time` with any `time_zone` you want to get the local time in that `time_zone`.

Comment: `The proposal was approved by LEWG and forwarded to LWG with the recommendation of targeting C++20 at the Albuquerque, NM meeting in Nov. 2017` niceee!